# In jenkins server npm install doesnt work throws an error . Is there any other command to install dependency instead of **npm install**

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins

I have Jenkin server it has a node and npm . I can see the Path of node and npm is **/bin/node** and **/bin/npm** . If I try to know the version of both I got it . The version for node is **v6.11.1** and npm is **3.10.10**.
The Problem i am facing there is if try to run **npm install** my angular 2 app . The responds shows below exception

```
+ cd ui
+ npm cache clean
+ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 User not found : @angular/platform-browser
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@angular/platform-browser' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'ui'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I have tried these command's still doesnt work , commands below are

```
npm cache clean 
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Below is my angular 2 `package.json` file ,

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build":"ng build --prod --base-href"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

While I **npm update -g** my node and npm below error occured ,

```
+ cd ui
+ npm cache clean
+ npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
+ npm update -g
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/asap
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream-npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-git-url
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/realize-package-specifier
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/jsprim/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/strip-ansi
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/write-file-atomic
- asap@2.0.5 node_modules/npm/node_modules/asap
- fstream@1.0.10 node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream
- fstream-npm@1.2.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream-npm
- normalize-git-url@3.0.2 node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-git-url
- realize-package-specifier@3.0.3 node_modules/npm/node_modules/realize-package-specifier
/usr/lib
└── npm@5.4.0 

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "update" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/asap
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/asap'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/asap'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/asap' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Please suggest me If any thing I am doing wrong . Advance Thanks !! .

Comment: Can you run npm install on your local environment ?

Comment: @MorLajb  **local** you meant my desktop correct . If yes In my desktop everything works perfectly ..  If not desktop  could plz explain me bit more .., what is `local` you said

Comment: And it's the same npm version ?

Comment: no its different in desktop the version i am using for  node is v6.11.2 and npm is 3.10.10 @MorLajb

Answer (score 1):

Your commands are right, just npm can't found the package, which is mostly caused by internet.

Comment: are you sure this error occured by internet issue ??`

Comment: yes, I always face this issue, eeeeeee, as you know, China has an internet wall.....@SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: haha  .., how to overcome this issue because in that server i dont have any permission even read as well .., I need to explain them so could yu please tell me the reason behind this ???

Comment: One way to use VPN(it still failed in most cases), otherwise change registry to taobao registry, just this: https://registry.npm.taobao.org @SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: where do I change that registry in my angular 2 app .or any other ??., sorry i am questioning you again and again because i am new bee to jenkins area bro

Comment: It's nothing to do with Jenkins, It's about your project, check this to change your registry, remember to clean cache. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry @SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: so i understood i need to try like this in my jenkins job `npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org/` is this corrrect .., if not  let me know .., ! @ Summer X

Comment: enennenen........... you can try it, because you are not in China. Before changing to this, try to be sure you can get access to internet at server, then check your dependencies are right. @SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: `npm ERR! This request requires auth credentials. Run npm login and repeat the request.npm ERR! ` I tried that registry it shown like above error is that error you expected ., or i need to add any other information , plz let me know @Summer X

Comment: Your server can't allow you to get access to Chinese server, because taobao registry is at china, maybe you need to check your server internet, you just npm err on @angular/platform-browser, or all packages?  @SakiSureshAnand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152709/discussion-between-summer-x-and-sakthisureshanand).

Comment: Actually , I gave `npm install` suddenly that error came , also i checked my WAR `node_modules` doesnt exist  . So i am thinking now all the packages . @Summer X

Comment: ok, that's the problem is your server internet access. you can't install any package in your jenkins server.  And I'm sorry that i can't chart because i'm at company...@SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: If its internet issue why ur china registry want login credentials .., it should also ends with some other error right friend

Comment: yes, but your internet access error is not that you can't get access to internet, but your internet rights.  @SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: i understood like i need to enable any port to download from the node dependency in my server @Summer X

Comment: i have updated my question using `npm update -g`  could u please see that if yu get any clue about internet issue rights

Comment: If you can't login to server, maybe by ssh, then write some bash to npm install package to verify whether you can install package or not.  if you can install package, then maybe the problem is  your have wrong dependencies ; if you can't install package, that's your internet issue. But firstly, try to verify your internet issues. @SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: friend, you have no write rights. @SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: yes , friend .., I would like to come china and sit with you clear the error then come back ..., if this dream  come true ..., WOWW felling i wil get ..., just kidding you man ..., @Summer X

Comment: sorry that i always face 404 error, always than you can imagine. Don't come china, has difficult to get access to stackoverflow, huhu.... @SakthiSureshAnand

Comment: finally  i manually did build and uploaded  the dist in my github buddy ...,

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the [node plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin)

to make sure it's not npm version.

if it still doesn't work , try run manually the npm on the Jenkins machine to verify you have all required access to the internet.

Comment: Actually @Mor Lajb I dont have root / admin access to see the manage jenkins option in that server .., Are you mentioning that one or different please correct me if i am understood wrong

Comment: so verify that you can run it on the Jenkins machine

Comment: Actually @Mor Lajb , I dont have access even ssh that server , thats why i am not able todo the stuff what you said .,.

Comment: that server access has some onsite team guys , so dont know why this error is occurs i surfed a lot about this every one says like my thousandth time its working , miracle ... something something ..., could you please explain why this issue comes , so tht i can move forward this to onsite team **see this reason might be an issue so plz check like ** @Mor Lajb

Comment: i have updated my question , using `npm update -g ` command could u please check if you get any clue related internet issues or internet rights issues

Comment: I am not an NPM expert , my answer stays the same.
you need to verify that you can npm install on the Jenkins machine.